# How to return the value found as "True" in a sumproduct(countif(**)) function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I have a large array (1600 rows x 26 columns) and I want to search for a word from the "Search List" (1400 rows) in that would be in any cell in the array. I have `SumProduct(countif())` that returns `True`/`False` but how can I return the found word in the row in which it was found?

I would like the output to be the word from the "Search List" that was found in the "Search Array" that caused the `sumproduct(countif())` to return as `TRUE`.

Comment: What word would you want to return, the actual search value or a value from a certain column in the row where the search value was found?

Comment: Ideally the search value from the "search list" would be the return output.

Comment: So just include another if true statement.....